# What was the earliest version of Windows with a limits.h header?

Tags: c, windows, posix

I'm doing some development work on Flex. I'd like to use <limits.h>, but there is a Windows port of this code, so I need to know:

What's the oldest version of Windows in which the native toolchain supports <limits.h>?

If my question should have been "what's the oldest toolchain version?" please consider it to have been phrased that way.

If I'm otherwise asking this question stupidly due to my vast ignorance of Windows, please correct the question.

Basically I'm looking for the year back past which I would be sacrificing portability if a user hasn't upgraded their toolchain since.

Comment: `limits.h` is part of standard C since C was first standardized.

Comment: If you mean Microsoft's C/C++ compilers, back in the times of 16-bit Windows 3.x Visual C++ 1.5 came with a `limits.h` stating `Copyright (c) 1985-1992, Microsoft Corporation`.

Comment: Windows doesn't come with a *"standard toolchain"*. Availability of a Standard C header file has no bearing on the supported platforms. This is true especially for the *limits.h* header file that doesn't generate any code.